# No Information on Google Analytics Dashboard for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics, dashboard

I am using Google Analytics iOS SDK V3 on my app as follows:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)setupGoogleAnalytics
{
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"myUAID"];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
    ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kTrackingPreferenceKey];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupGoogleAnalytics];
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home View"];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
}
```

I leave the app running in the simulator but I get nothing on the Google Analytics dashboard. Am I missing something? Notice I am using the [latest SDK v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/).

Answer (score 0):

What does `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kTrackingPreferenceKey]` return on that device?

It could be that your code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` is setting `optOut = YES` all of the time, preventing data from getting saved.

Google's sample code mentions `kTrackingPreferenceKey`, but I think it's just an example of how you *could* store a tracking preference.